# Is my sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I want to create a quote which is:

> "You have everything when you had nothing".

Is it correct?

I am trying to say that once one starts to realize that we have nothing, that is the moment we just have everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide whether you wish to say something very terse and epigrammatic, or something a little less terse, but a little clearer and less ambiguous.

You have everything when you have nothing.

You have everything when you expect nothing.

Once we understand that we have nothing, we have everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is *almost* correct.. 
Just change the "had" with "have" at the end of the sentence. So, it would be like this,

> You have everything when you **have** nothing.

Or you can change the *have* at the start of the sentence with *had*, but that would make it a past tense.

Comment: but it is wrong if i just leave as it is, because i'm intentionally put "had" at the end. to show that we will have everything "after" we realize we have nothing. is it still wrong ? please advise.

Comment: @Tengku The verb *have* does not include the notion of realizing what one has (or does not have), so this would not work in English.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is correct but it ought to be **have** instead of **had**.

> You have everything when you **had** nothing.

In this sentence, you used **had** instead of **have**. you are specifying that you **had** nothing and it still continues. So this isn't a future event.

> You have everything when you **have** nothing.

Now, you are specifying that if you have nothing, you will have everything. There is a condition as you can see.